# More number of parameters from C# to Python

Tags: c#, python

In my application, I am passing arguments to a Python file. The code i have written is :

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} 
                              {1}",@"C:\Work\Scripts\XML_Parsing.py", 
                               asset_id.Text);
```

This works fine for me. The problem is, I have almost 20 values to be passed as arguments to the Python file. Is there any better way to pass these values to Python?

Comment: Can you change the python code?

Answer (score 0):

String.Join seems like it might work for your purpose.

```
string[] python_args = new string[] {
    @"C:\Work\Scripts\XML_Parsing.py", "arg1", "arg2"
};
process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", python_args);
```

Comment: Doesn't this gives a one string? I don't want to separate out all the strings again in my Python code.

Comment: You dont have to separate them all out manually, you can iterate over them with sys.argv.